# c: issues when allocating 2d char array dynamically?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to allocate a 2D char array to be accessed like `ary[i][j]`, using this code:

```
#define stringmaxlen 20

void do_alloc( char ***vals, int valscount ){
    *vals = (char**) calloc( sizeof( char** ), valscount );
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i<valscount; i++ )
        *vals[i] = (char*) calloc( sizeof( char* ), stringmaxlen );
}

int main( ){
    //......
    char** ary;
    do_alloc( &ary, 10 );
    strcpy( ary[0], "test" );
    //......
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes an overflow somewhere and the program have a bug in execution, I got some references from here for the dynamic allocation: http://staff.science.nus.edu.sg/~phywjs/CZ1102/lecture20/sld014.htm.

I like to know what's wrong here and how to solve the issue, thanks.

Comment: The parameters you use for `calloc` are in reversed order as you can see from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) and [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f8w183e.aspx); although I don't really know whether it would cause an erroneous behaviour.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin The order of parameters to `calloc` is irrelevant on any platform that I know of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got the operator precedence wrong: `*vals[i]` evaluates as `*(vals[i])`, not as `(*vals)[i]`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence for details.

The fix is to change `*vals[i]` to `(*vals)[i]`.

Also, the allocation `*vals[i] = (char*) calloc( sizeof( char* ), stringmaxlen );` is wrong. It allocates way too much memory because it allocates space for `stringmaxlen` *pointers*, but you need only `stringmaxlen` characters.

Comment: yeah! that's it, now the issue is fixed, the precision is important! thank you man!

Answer (score 3):

I want to add the following to cmaster's answer.

Instead of

```
*vals = (char**) calloc( sizeof( char** ), valscount );
```

use

```
*vals = (char**) calloc( sizeof( char* ), valscount );
```

Instead of

```
    (*vals)[i] = (char*) calloc( sizeof(char*), stringmaxlen );
```

use

```
    (*vals)[i] = (char*) calloc( sizeof(char), stringmaxlen );
```

In the first case, the size of memory allocated doesn't change since `sizeof(char**)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)`. However that's not true with the second case. `sizeof(char)` is 1 while `sizeof(char*)` is larger -- 4 for 32 bit hardware, 8 for 64 bit hardware.

More importantly, it clarifies the intention -- that you would like to allocate memory for `stringmaxlen` characters, not `stringmaxlen` pointers to characters.

Comment: You could have avoided these errors by using the idiom: `P = calloc(N, sizeof *P);`, e.g. `*vals = calloc( valscount, sizeof **vals );` etc.